# Returning disposable object from within using block

Tags: c#, memory-management, .net-4.0, memory-leaks, using

I'm noticing a lot of byte[] getting stuck in memory when profiling my program.  I did some digging and found the majority of the instances created in some manner like this:

```
public byte[] CreateBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var start = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        using (var memStr = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            //do stuff
            return start.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The returned byte[] is then passed to other methods and is used in creating another `MemoryStream` from within another using block:

```
using (var uncompressedStream = new MemoryStream(uncompressedData))
{
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //Do some compression
    }
}

myObject.Bytes = uncompressedData;
uncompressedData = null;

return myObject;
```

(`uncompressedData` is the value returned from CreateBytes()).

My question is, **when does the byte[] get cleaned up?**  Do I specifically need to set it to null, and if so, where?  After the second using block I no longer need it, but if I simply put `uncompressedData = null;` I'm not sure that's going to reclaim the memory.

I would've thought that the using statement in `CreateBytes(byte[] bytes)` would've disposed of the bytes, but since it's returning a reference does that postpone and/or forego the disposal?

**EDIT**: I added another line of code.  Since I'm storing the uncompressedBtyes in another object, setting uncompressedData to null is pointless and the byte[] will live as long as `myObject` (or until `myObject.Bytes` is set to null), correct?

Comment: `using` only disposes off the unmanaged objects as `MemoryStream` in your code. `bytes` is managed by GC process i.e. garbage collected when appropriate (non-deterministic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The byte[] gets cleaned up when two conditions are both satisfied:

- There are no references to that memory block
- The garbage collector decides to collect that memory block

The GC runs at non-deterministic times based on a variety of factors.

Comment: cyclic references not referenced through the root references will get cleaned too. Trivial point. :)

Answer (score 1):

The byte array, just like any other managed object in memory, is eligible for garbage collection as soon as it is no longer accessible from any root reference.  You can trust the GC to know when that's happened, and to intelligently schedule times to actually do the clean up of eligible objects.  Try not to worry about when an object that's eligible for cleanup is actually cleaned up, chances are the GC knows better than you.

Comment: I don't worry about that, what worries me is that it isn't getting cleaned up because it's apparently not eligible for GC (because it's probably referenced somewhere).

Comment: @Devin We aren't seeing enough of your code to be able to point out areas where you are referencing the array after you no longer need it, if that's even the case.  It could just be that the GC hasn't bothered to clean it up yet, or that you actually need to keep the data around for that long.

Comment: I added some code that should essentially demonstrate what's happening in my code.

Comment: @Devin Not really, or at least not enough.  You just show that you're assigning the array to yet another variable, and you don't show enough code to know the lifetime of that other variable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Erics answer:

When you are sure you do not more need that `byte[]`, assign to it `null`.

This will not guarantee that memory will be reclaimed *now*, neither that it will be reclimed after, this is just a way to *help* `GC` to identify it like a subject for collection.

Comment: in almost all cases, when you don't need something anymore it's because it's about to go out of scope, so there's no need to set it to null.  If that's not true, it's more likely that your variables are scoped at a higher level then they should be.  I virtually never have had the need to set a variable to `null` just so it could be collected.

Comment: @Servy: agree on this, but as I mantioned, this is basic good rules guideline in complex interactions, where may be you're dealing with a lot of nested calls, to functions and types you don't care about (or can not care about). If there is some point in workflow where you are sure you do not more need that stuff, assign to it null. In general, in most common cases, I would agree with you instead.

Comment: Actually the cases where you have lots of complicated nested calls is exactly when you don't need to set variables to null, as they tend to be scoped properly.  Where you tend to see variable set to null is when you see the several hundred/thousand line of code methods that are doing dozens of entirely separate operations all within the same scope.  Since you don't have different scopes for each operation, local variables created at the start will be alive throughout.  Some people choose to just set the variables to null so they can be freed rather than refactoring the code into more methods.

Comment: @Servy: Sure, by refactoring you can resolve *many* problems in software, not only this one. I, naturally, refer to cases where the refactoring is not possible or not desirable (risky, no time to invest and so on...)

Comment: @Servy I also agree that setting items to null is generally unnecessary.  However, in the case above, (if I understand correctly) uncompressedData will go out of scope, but I believe it's simply pointing to a byte[] that was created outside of the scope, so uncompressedData will no longer point to that byte[], but it's still existing in memory (and I don't know where, which is the problem.)

Comment: This is a bad guideline. It makes sense to set a field in a long-lived object to null, because it's in a long-lived object. Actually assigning a local to null will only make it live a few nanoseconds longer - assuming the compiler doesn't just compile it away as useless - because it's a few nanoseconds before the register or stack space can be used for something else.

Comment: @JonHanna: agree, but considering the point of OP's about a fact that even assigning a `null` to **this** object it appears that memory is not reclaimed, one possible reasons could be that it was assigned to some other global/long-running reference.

Comment: @Devin The variable is no long in scope, so whatever it points to is irrelevant.  The GC will only consider references that are in scope when collecting.  You have not shown enough code for us to see the entire lifetime of every variable that ever holds onto that array, which is what we would need to know in order to tell you if you're holding onto a reference to it for too long.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statement really has nothing to do with the `byte` array you are returning.

The `MemoryStream` is disposable, and disposal of that object is what the `using` statement is managing (note that disposal is not the same as garbage collection, but is typically a precursor thereto).

When you call `ToArray()`, you are creating something new that is not disposable; once it is out of scope, it will be cleaned up by the garbage collector at an indeterminate time (this is typically a well optimized process).